# Using iTunes COM interface to transfer files to an App

Tags: c#, ipad

I've been tasked with building a data syncing application in C# that will sync files to an application on an iPad.  Due to the sensitive nature of the files being transferred, I cannot use any cloud services, and the file transfer needs to happen via the USB connection to the iPad.

**Requirements**

1) The syncing program must run on Windows 7

2) The sync CANNOT occur over a webpage, or public network.  Any network used must be local to the machine being transferred, and work over the USB connection.

3) The transfer must happen programmatically, opening iTunes->App->App Name->Documents manually is cumbersome.

4) The app will never be added to the app store, so break as may of the Apple guidelines as you want!

**What I Know**

1) I've found [Peer-talk](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk), but it does not have a C# interface (or file transfer interface).

2) I've also found [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2152/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009179-CH1-SUBSECTION18), but its light on technical details

Comment: "Due to the sensitive nature of the files being transferred, I cannot use any cloud services" -- was that decided before this week?!

Comment: Yes - currently all the files are being transferred via iTunes.  We cannot change that requirement.